# How to enable real text prediction for android / stock keyboard on LG optimus one?

Tags: keyboard, lg-optimus-one, text-prediction

The title says it all but i will explain a bit more.

I have a LG optimus one phone with android 2.2 froyo. It comes with two keyboards, the LG one with working text prediction and the Android / Stock keyboard (what's the official name?) that does not seem to have access to the language dictionaries because it ONLY predicts my contacts' names!

Is there a way I can fix this? I really want to use the Android/Stock keyboard with working text prediction and voice input. I don't want any alternative like swift or similar.

Thanks a lot

dmeu

Comment: My stock Android keyboard works with text prediction.  What's shown as the name in Settings -> Locale and text?

Comment: in my menu: 'settings -> language & keyboard' is shown "select language, "lg keyboard", "android keyboard", "user dictionary"... sorry i didnt get notified about the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [this review](http://contadorwanarua.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/lg-optimus-one-review/) of the LG Optimus One which includes this quote:

> The standard Android keyboard’s text
>   prediction is disabled; it doesn’t
>   seem to have access to the system’s
>   language dictionaries.  So if you want
>   word prediction, the LG keyboard it
>   is.

Looks like you're going to have to go with a third-party app solution or flash a new ROM to your phone.