# How do I get dictionary suggestions while typing?

Tags: keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable real text prediction for android / stock keyboard on LG optimus one?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/how-to-enable-real-text-prediction-for-android-stock-keyboard-on-lg-optimus-on)

I'm using android version 2.2.2 and the default keyboard (at least it appears as 'Android keyboard' in the configuration menu). I have suggestions enabled, but I only get autocomplete suggestions for my contacts, I don't get suggestions for common words. It doesn't really matter which language I choose for the input (portuguese or english).

The device is a LG Optimus One (P500h), and it came with another keyboard installed (called 'LG keyboard'). If I choose this keyboard as the input method, I get the suggestions. The problem is that this keyboard is really bad, and I like the default one.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

if you're willing to switch keyboards, you have several incredible options.

1. [SwiftKey](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&feature=featured-apps) has (by far) the best word prediction so far, and tracks how much it improves your typing speed, which is around 30% for most people.
2. [FlexT9](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nuance.flext9.input&feature=search_result) has some great features (including traceType, like [Swype](http://swypeinc.com/)), and pretty good word prediction, but not quite up to par with SwiftKey.
3. [TouchPal](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cootek.smartinputv5&feature=search_result) is supposed to be the next revolution in keyboards. It combines the first two strategies (word prediction and traceType) for incredibly fast input. **As of now, it does not support traceType, only word prediction.** But look for the update soon ;)

These are my favorites, the first two are paid and the last is free, but you might be able to find free or trial versions of the other two. Let us know if there's anything else we can clear up for you!